# How can I extract a number from a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, numbers

I have a string in JavaScript (e.g., `#box2`), and I just want the `2` from it.

I tried:

```
var thestring = $(this).attr('href');
var thenum = thestring.replace(/(^.+)(\w\d+\w)(.+$)/i, '$2');
alert(thenum);
```

It still returns `#box2` in the alert. How can I get it to work?

It needs to accommodate for any length number attached on the end.

Comment: you can simply do like this . it will work well .



var thestring = $(this).attr('href');



var thenum = parsefloat(thestring);



alert(thenum);

Comment: this code works fine for me but for one case , I have a string '2.5/mile' and I want to extract 2.5 out of this. Above code gives me 25 instead of 2.5

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1862130/1066234

Answer (score 857, accepted):

For this specific example,

```
 var thenum = thestring.replace(/^\D+/g, ''); // Replace all leading non-digits with nothing
```

In the general case:

```
 thenum = "foo3bar5".match(/\d+/)[0] // "3"
```

Here's a bonus: regex generator.

```js
function getre(str, num) {
  if(str === num)
    return 'nice try';
  var res = [/^\D+/g,/\D+$/g,/^\D+|\D+$/g,/\D+/g,/\D.*/g, /.*\D/g,/^\D+|\D.*$/g,/.*\D(?=\d)|\D+$/g];
  for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++)
    if(str.replace(res[i], '') === num)
      return 'num = str.replace(/' + res[i].source + '/g, "")';
  return 'no idea';
};

function update() {
  $ = function(x) { return document.getElementById(x) };
  var re = getre($('str').value, $('num').value);
  $('re').innerHTML = 'Numex speaks: <code>' + re + '</code>';
}
```

```html
<p>Hi, I'm Numex, the Number Extractor Oracle.
<p>What is your string? <input id="str" value="42abc"></p>
<p>What number do you want to extract? <input id="num" value="42"></p>
<p><button onclick="update()">Insert Coin</button></p>
<p id="re"></p>
```

Comment: -1, `"#box2_col3".replace( /^\D+/g, '')` should have shown `2`, not `2_col3`.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: I don't see any reference to `#box2_col3` in the question.

Comment: Yes there is no reference of `#box2_col3`. But see the regex OP used (`\w)(.+$)`)which clearly indicates there are other characters after the number.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: read the question again: "number attached __on the end__".

Comment: in that case your pattern also fails if there is number before the end.

Comment: You could make `replace` work with leading numbers by using: `theString.replace(/^.*\D+/g, '');`, but shiplu.mokadd.im's solution is better.

Comment: how about there are two number in a string? eg: [55-57]

Comment: var thenum = thestring.replace( /[^\d]+/g, '');

Comment: Is there a point of extracting a number from a string if you already have the number? Seems otherwise you would just search for a contained string to see if its there. Seems it'd be more useful without putting in a particular number to extract.

Comment: you do not need `^` as I think: `.replace(/\D+/g, '')`

Comment: \D mist be \d then work. When I use \D, I got **NAH** to number

Comment: A problem I've come across with this solution is that it will not carry the negative over for negative numbers. Trying to extract a negative number will only give you the positive number.

Comment: FYI, for whatever reason, `thestring.match(/\d+/)[0]` seems to be be about **10% to 20% faster** than `thestring.replace(/^\D+/g,'')`, based on millions of tests.

Comment: All fun and games until you realize you don't know what the number is andwhat is around, and the number can have decimals with unknows decimal separator.

Answer (score 331):

You should try the following:

```js
var txt = "#div-name-1234-characteristic:561613213213";
var numb = txt.match(/\d/g);
numb = numb.join("");
console.log(numb);
```

Comment: nice answer but what if I want the set of numbers separately. i.e. 1234, 5616133...

Comment: Or one-liner + parsing to integer: `parseInt(txt.match(/\d/g).join(''), 10)`

Comment: `" $  20.0 ".match(/\d/g).join('')`  => "200" (just saying)

Comment: this solution will not extract float. the regex should be `/[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g`

Answer (score 170):

I think this regular expression will serve your purpose:

```
var num = txt.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
```

Where `txt` is your string.

It basically rips off anything that is not a digit.

I think you can achieve the same thing by using this as well:

```
var num = txt.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

Comment: `/[^0-9]/g` +1 for readability. Also used with most of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1862130/1066234

Comment: best solution! thank you

Answer (score 79):

Try the following: `string.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');` This will delete all non-digit characters, leaving only digits in the string

```
function retnum(str) { 
    var num = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
    return parseInt(num,10); 
}
```

```js
console.log('abca12bc45qw'.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
console.log('#box2'.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
```

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer, since it does replace all non-numbers globally and btw, `/[^0-9]/g` can be replaced with `/[^\d]/g`.

Answer (score 61):

Using the *[match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)* function.

```js
var thenum = "0a1bbb2".match(/\d+$/)[0];
console.log(thenum);
```

Comment: Also you can add unary '+' to make it integer
var thenum = +thestring.match(/\d+$/)[0];

Comment: I guess this doesn't work for > 1 digit numbers?  (I understand the question was for 1 digit numbers, but I'm looking at numbers possible > 10.)

Comment: @nissemand Dont **guess**. Try yourself. Even you didn't see the fiddle.

Comment: Love this. A simplest way to extract the number into a variable without touch or modify the element. I would appreciate a combo with each for a multple coincidences inside a string. ie the string 12a55 report the last number, not all.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev it should not. Check the original question. Specially the last line. Number should be at the end.

Comment: It' such a brilliant solution! But can you explain more about the way accessing the match part using [0], cause I cannot find any data mention it.

Comment: @hayley Check the return value of the `match` function in [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#return_value).

Answer (score 47):

And this is a snippet which extracts prices with currency and formatting:

```
var price = "£1,739.12";
parseFloat(price.replace(/[^\d\.]*/g, '')); // 1739.12
```

Comment: What if I want 1,739.12 ?

Answer (score 35):

I tried ***all*** the combinations cited in the previous answer with this code and got it working. It was the only one that worked on that string → *(12) 3456-7890*

```js
var str = "(12) 3456-7890";
str.replace(/\D+/g, '');
```

Result: `"1234567890"`

Obs: I know that a string like that will not be on the attribute, but whatever, the solution is better, because it’s more complete.

Comment: i think better will be `str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number)` it will return an array

Answer (score 19):

You may use the great [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) method.

It will convert the leading digits to a number:

```
parseInt("-10px");
// Will give you -10
```

Comment: this only works when the number is at the beginning of the string

Comment: its returning NaN

Answer (score 16):

You can extract numbers from a string using a regex expression:

```
let string = "xxfdx25y93.34xxd73";
let res = string.replace(/\D/g, "");
console.log(res);
```

Output: 25933473

Wrap it into a [vanilla JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software) function:

```
function onlyNumbers(text){
    return text.replace(/\D/g, "");
}
```

Answer (score 12):

For a string such as `#box2`, this should work:

```
var thenum = thestring.replace(/^.*?(\d+).*/,'$1');
```

jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/dmeku/

Answer (score 12):

```js
function justNumbers(string)
{
   var numsStr = string.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
   return parseInt(numsStr);
}

console.log(justNumbers('abcdefg12hijklmnop'));
```

You can do a function like this

```
function justNumbers(string)
{
    var numsStr = string.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    return parseInt(numsStr);
}
```

Remember: if the number has a zero in front of it, the int won’t have it

Answer (score 12):

To return an int from the string, you can do the following code. It removes all not number characters and returns an integer.

```
Number("strin[g]3".replace(/\D+/g, ""))
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to parse a number from a price like $6,694.20, it can be done this way:

```js
parseFloat('$6,694.20'.replace(/^\D|,+/g, ''))
```

Or via a function:

```js
function parsePrice(value) {
  return parseFloat(value.replace(/^\D|,+/g, ''))
}

parsePrice('$6,694.20') // 6694.2
```

Comment: Note that in case there may be more than one character at the beginning of the string which is not part of the number, you'll want to use `value.replace(/^\D+|,+/g, '')`

Answer (score 8):

```
let str = "Total Work Duration: 189.56 Hrs.Present: 23.5 Absent: 2";

/* The provided regex globally matches the character
   "." and a digit from the string */
let numArr = str.match(/[\d\.]+/g)

/* It returns an array [189.56, ., 23.5, 2], and
   uses the filter function to remove the '.' */
numArr = numArr.filter(n => n != '.')
console.log(numArr)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a regular expression.

```
var txt="some text 2";
var numb = txt.match(/\d/g);
alert (numb);
```

That will alert 2.

Comment: -1 multiple digits will not be captured and for using array in alert

Answer (score 5):

If someone need to preserve dots in extracted numbers:

```
var some = '65,87 EUR';
var number = some.replace(",",".").replace(/[^0-9&.]/g,'');
console.log(number); // returns 65.87
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Underscore.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore.js)' string library as follows:

```
var common = "#box"
var href = "#box1"

_(href).strRight(common)
```

The result will be: 1

See: *[Underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string)*

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/Vyqtt/

**HTML code:**

```
<p>
    <a href="#box1" >img1</a>
    <a href="#box2" >img2</a>
    <a href="#box3" >img3</a>
    <a href="#box4" >img4</a>
</p>
<div style="font-size:30px"></div>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
var comm = "#box"
$('a').click(function() {
  $('div').html(_($(this).attr('href')).strRight(comm))})
```

If you have a suffix as follows:

```
href="box1az"
```

You can use the following demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/Vyqtt/1/

```
function retrieveNumber(all, prefix, suffix) {
  var left = _(all).strRight(prefix);
  return _(left).strLeft(suffix);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that checks for no data:

```
var someStr = 'abc'; // Add 123 to string to see the inverse

var thenum = someStr.match(/\d+/);

if (thenum != null)
{
    console.log(thenum[0]);
}
else
{
    console.log('Not a number');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check the below JavaScript code. There you can get only a number.

```js
var txt = "abc1234char5678#!9";
var str = txt.match(/\d+/g, "") + '';
var s = str.split(',').join('');
alert(Number(s));
```

Output: `1234567789`

Answer (score 3):

```
var elValue = "-12,erer3  4,-990.234sdsd";

var isNegetive = false;
if(elValue.indexOf("-") == 0)
    isNegetive = true;

elValue = elValue.replace( /[^\d\.]*/g, '');
elValue = isNaN(Number(elValue)) ? 0 : Number(elValue);

if(isNegetive)
    elValue = 0 - elValue;

alert(elValue); // -1234990.234
```

Comment: Ad an explanation. E.g. why you use namely this regex.

Comment: Where was this copied from? The misspelling "[negetive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/negative#Adjective)" might be a good signature.

Answer (score 2):

With [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), how to get numbers from a string, for example:

```
String myString = "my 2 first gifts were made by my 4 brothers";
myString = myString.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
System.out.println("myString: " + myString);
```

The result of `myString` is "`24`".

You can see an example of this running code at **http://ideone.com/iOCf5G**.

Comment: java !== javascript  - replaceAll does not exist in standard javascript. Only some libraries like jQuery have that method. In the future, you should clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Use this one-line code to get the first number in a string without getting errors:

```
var myInt = parseInt(myString.replace(/^[^0-9]+/, ''), 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Written without a regular expression:

```js
// Without Regex

function extractNumber(string) {
  let numArray = string.split('').map(item => {
    if (typeof +item === 'number' && !isNaN(+item)) 
      return +item
  })
  return +numArray.join('')
}

extractNumber('@1200milion$')  // 1200
```

Comment: What are all the leading pluses (`+`) for?

Comment: @PeterMortensen  " + " is a shorthand to convert a string to number 
+item === Number(item)

Answer (score 1):

This answer will cover most of the scenarios. I came across this situation when a user tried to copy paste the phone number.

```
$('#help_number').keyup(function() {
  $(this).val().match(/\d+/g).join("")
});
```

Explanation:

```
str = "34%^gd 5-67 6-6ds"

str.match(/\d+/g)
```

It will give an array of strings as output:

```
["34", "56766"]
```

```
str.match(/\d+/g).join("")
```

[join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) will convert and concatenate that array data into a single string.

Output:

```
"3456766"
```

In my example, I needed the output as *209-356-6788*, so I used [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
$('#help_number').keyup(function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().match(/\d+/g).join("").replace(/(\d{3})\-?(\d{3})\-?(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3'))
});
```

Comment: Is some library presumed? [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)? [Underscore.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore.js)?

Comment: Yes, I have used JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "(/\d+/g)" which will remove all non-number text, but it will still be a string at this point. If you create a variable and "parseInt" through the match, you can set the new variables to the array values. Here is an example of how I got it to work:

```
    var color = $( this ).css( "background-color" );
    var r = parseInt(color.match(/\d+/g)[0]);
    var g = parseInt(color.match(/\d+/g)[1]);
    var b = parseInt(color.match(/\d+/g)[2]);
```

Comment: Hello! This question already has an accepted answer. Before looking at answered questions, please consider looking at [unanswered ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) first. If you do, however, have something to add to an answered question, please consider reading other answers thoroughly first.

Comment: Re *""(/\d+/g)" which will remove all non-number text"*: Really? It presumably comes with a qualification. That needs to be [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62786482/edit) in the answer. (But ***** ***without*** ***** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)

Answer (score 1):

In one of my projects I had to take a rating value from a string. This is what I used:

```
let text = '#xbox2'
let num = text.trim().
  split('').
  map(num => Number(num)).
  filter(x => Number.isInteger(x))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
changeStrangeDate(dateString: string) {
  var sum = 0;
  var numbers = dateString.match(/\d+/g);
  if (numbers.length > 1) {
    numbers.forEach(element => {
        sum += parseInt(element);
      }
    );
  }
  console.log(new Date(sum).toDateString());
  return new Date(sum).toUTCString();
}
```

You can do it like that and then call a function where you need it, with a parameter.

```
this.changeStrangeDate('/Date(1551401820000-0100)/');
```