# how to extract floating numbers from strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have xml content in textarea which can be of the form,

```
<tag value="20.434" value1="-12.334" />
```

Or

```
20.434 -12.334
```

I want to be able to extract the two floating numbers per line.

Comment: This question seems to valid since I can't answer here so posting a link to answer that helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/34311427/6517383

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the regex `/[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g` in conjunction with [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to parse the numbers and [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to turn them into floats:

```
var regex = /[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g;

var str = '<tag value="20.434" value1="-12.334" />';
var floats = str.match(regex).map(function(v) { return parseFloat(v); });
console.log(floats);

var str2 = '20.434 -12.334';
var floats2 = str2.match(regex).map(function(v) { return parseFloat(v); });
console.log(floats2);

var strWithInt = "200px";
var ints = strWithInt.match(regex).map(function(v) { return parseFloat(v); });
console.log(ints);
```

[See demo code here.](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/vqjKt/26/)

Comment: var regex = /[+-]?\d+\.*\d+/g; will fetch both integers and floats

Comment: @JayaramRPai That's nice, but has some minor problems: it would not match something simple, such as `1` and would match stuff like `1......1`. For both integers and floats, I'd suggest adapting it to something like `var regex = /[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g;`.

Comment: @acdcjunior, I had slightly modified my regex to `var regex = /[+-]?\d*\.*\d+/g;` but I did not check for the `1......1` possibility. Yours is perfect, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can always load the string into jQuery and get the attributes:

```
$('<tag value="20.434" value1="-12.334" />').attr('value')
$('<tag value="20.434" value1="-12.334" />').attr('value1')
```

In your case regex is probably the better route.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to use parseFloat once you figure out how to extract the numbers from between your text... How you extract those numbers depends entirely on what that text is.  Most likely you'll split the entire text on a \s and then remove all the characters that aren't numbers and dots.  That should leave you with the floats... though again, impossible to say without seeing what the surrounding text looks like.

EDIT:
Ok now that you've changed your question the answer is that you'll simply grab the attributes named value and value1 and run parse float on what's in them. If your text area contains this XML you'll need to parse the XML first to get the attributes as objects.

Comment: The format can be either numbers in xml or just numbers. I don't want to restrict the format just to xml.

Comment: I'm not even sure what the question is... just run parseFloat on everything that might contain floats, check for isNaN() and if it's false then you have a float.