# Change regex to find decimals-Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the following string:

```
var string="0px 0px 4.5px";
```

Now let's say I want to extract the numbers from that string.
I will use the following regex:

```
var numbers=string.match(/\d+/g);
```

But what I get is:

```
["0","0","4"]
```

So you see that 4.5 was turned into an integer.So my question is how can I change the above regex to get floating numbers from a string

Comment: regex? pfft... `"0px 0px 4.5px".split(" ").map(parseFloat)`

Comment: @canon: Won't that spit out `["0px", "0px","4.5px"]`. Shouldn't it split on `px ` ? P.S: Checked it. It's works.

Comment: @noob That's what the `split()` returns, yes. But the call to `map()` then parses those values into floats. Try it in console.

Comment: Hey stribnez, not ony is [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374893/how-to-extract-floating-numbers-from-strings-in-javascript) the answer closed but the selected answer is _wrong_.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is already in comment by **canon**.

But since you added the <kbd>regex</kbd> tag here is solution.

**Regex:** `/(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)/g`

**Flags to use:**

- `g` for global search.

**Explanation:**

- `\d+` will match the integer part.
- `(?:\.\d+)?` will match the decimal part which is optional.
- `\.\d+` for numbers with only decimal part.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fF3iZ5/4)**

Comment: It was and it's also wrong :)

Comment: @Pointy: `*` will allow many decimal parts.

Comment: well my supposition that `4.px` is valid CSS doesn't seem to be true (though `4. + 4` is perfectly good JavaScript).

Comment: This will allow me to only get the first value which is "0" not all the values

Comment: @cssGEEK: Use global flag. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good one `(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)`

Explained

```
 (?:
      \d+                 # Digits
      (?: \. \d* )?       # Optional dot (digits optional)
   |                    # or,
      \. \d+              # Dot digits
 )
```

Comment: Oh yea ! to allow only decimal part too. Nice catch.

Comment: Yes that would be a good idea if it were true, as I thought it was until mere moments ago, that valid CSS can include something like `5.px`.

Comment: Well then the `5.` is matched.