# Extracting float number from string using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string, floating-point

I have a string in javascript:

```
ECTS: 7.5 pts
```

From this string I need to extract `7.5` and parse it to a float value..

I've tried searching, but none of the solutions I found did the trick. I've tried:

```
var regex = /^\d+\.\d{0,3}$/;
var string = "ECTS: 7.5 pts";
var number = parseFloat(string.match(regex));
console.log("number is: " + number);
```

I've tried with a couple of different regular expressions, but none of them have done the trick.

I've created this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/v4mdkj9a/) to illustrate the problem.

## EDIT1

I used to have this `/\d+/` as my regex, but that didn't include floating point numbers.

## EDIT2

I ended up using this as my regex `/[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g`

Updated [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/v4mdkj9a/10/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374893/how-to-extract-floating-numbers-from-strings-in-javascript

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I did check out this one already, and it didn't work. I tried it again and it did. Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

This works nicely, no need for regex:

```
var s = "ECTS: 7.5 pts";
var n = parseFloat(s.split(" ")[1]);
$("#test").text(n);
```

Comment: Nice solution, but I could run into problems with this one as I got a lot of these kinds of strings, and they are not all the same when it comes to spacings. Of course you couldn't know that. +1'ed your solution.

Answer (score 1):

did you try this?
`var digits = Number((/(\d+\.\d+)/.exec('ECTS: 7.5 pts') || []).pop());`