# Jquery - NaN error after running plugin to convert to USD $

Tags: javascript, jquery, parseint

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clone').click(function() {
    var target = $(this).closest('.groupcontainer');
    target.clone(true, true).insertAfter(target);
  });

  $('.input').on('input',function(){
    $(this).parent().children('.grouptotal').val($(this).val() *  
$(this).parent().children('.input2').val());
  $('.grouptotal').change();
  });

  $('.input2').on('input', function(){
    $(this).parent().children('.grouptotal').val($(this).val() * 
$(this).parent().children('.input').val());
     $('.grouptotal').change();
  });
  $('.input2').dblclick(function(){
    $(this).parent().children('.input2').autoNumeric('init', {aSign: "$ "});
  });  
  $('.grouptotal').dblclick(function(){
    $(this).parent().children('.grouptotal').autoNumeric('init', {aSign: "$ "});
  });
  $('#subtotal').dblclick(function(){
    $(this).parent().children('#subtotal').autoNumeric('init', {aSign: "$ "});
  });
  $('.reset').click(function(){
    $('.behindgroup').parent().children().find('input, textarea').val('');
  });
});  


$(document).on('change', '.grouptotal', function(){
  var sum = 0;
    $('.grouptotal').each(function(){
    sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $('#subtotal').val(sum);
      });
```

Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waynebunch/z61arav3/).

I have a function that does quantity * system = grouptotal.

My issue now is this.  I have a plugin (autoNumeric) that will convert `.grouptotal` to USD$.  However, when I double click it to convert, my `#subtotal` will change from a number to NaN.  I've tried putting parseInt in every place I can think of, but it always reverts to NaN after the plugin is run.  Prior to running the plugin, the `#subtotal` is fine, but they are not a dollar amount like I need.

I've changed `sum += +$(this).val();` to `sum += +parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;` but it just ends up returning 0 in `#subtotal`.

How do I get `#subtotal` to pull just the number from `.grouptotal` after I've run my plugin to convert to $USD?

I hope this makes sense..

Comment: what does `$(this).val()` return?

Comment: That returns total of `.grouptotal`  I have this because once I click the clone button, I want all of the `.grouptotal`s to be added up in `#subtotal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JavaScript, you could take advantage of regular expressions by doing something like this:

```
 '$45.00'.match(/\d+/)[0]
```

Being '$45.00' your subtotal.

This was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10003731/1301469)