# How to get a JS value from an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a variable called grabber that gets a class and I need to be able to compare the values of all the classes it grabs.

```
var grabber = document.getElementsByClassName("compareDiv");
```

It will return (5024)Votes or however many votes are listed on the div. I need to be able to compare them but from what I understand I would need to somehow make it an integer or omit certain characters so it can compare the value of the numbers? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003683/javascript-get-number-from-string

Comment: Grabber doesnt "return" anything. Especially not a string. It contains a group of dom elements. Your question makes no sense ..

Comment: My bad, so if it is returning the elements is there a way I could get just the number from it? Possibly convert it to a string then get just the number?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over elements, get their [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) and use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) (or [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) if values were fractional) to convert the value to a number:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('compareDiv'),
    count    = elements.length,
    numbers  = [];

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    numbers.push(parseInt(elements[i].textContent));
}

// The `numbers` array contains your numbers.
```