# Javascript getting number from string

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I have a string:

```
var example = 'sorted-by-' + number;
```

Where number variable can be any positive integer. I don't know how to reverse this process, not knowing how many digits this number has. I want to get from example string a number at the end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript get number from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003683/javascript-get-number-from-string)

Comment: You question is deplicate see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003683/javascript-get-number-from-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var outputNumber = example.substring(10);
```

This is the simple solution because example string always start with 'sorted-by-'.

Answer (score 2):

```
let num = + string.substr(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String#replace` function to replace `sorted-by-` to empty string and after that convert left part to a number:

```js
var example = 'sorted-by-' + 125;
var num = +example.replace('sorted-by-', '');

console.log(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split string at `-` and get last element using `pop()`.

```js
var example = 'sorted-by-' + 100.99
var n = +(example.split('-').pop())

console.log(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `regex` for this.

```js
var number = 245246245;
var example = 'sorted-by-' + number;

var res = example.match(/^sorted-by-(\d+)/);
console.log(+res[1]);
```