# Get numbers only from a value - replacing characters and symbols

Tags: javascript

I need to get numbers only (strip commas and currency symbol) from a value in an id called "price". I have the following:

```
function() {
var element = document.querySelector('*[id^="price"]');
var price = element.innerHTML.match(/\d*\.\d*/)[0];
return price;
}
```

This works fine of the value is something like "£10.50". But if my value has a comma such as "£2,050.00" it returns "050.00".

How do i get just numbers and replace any currency symbols and commas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript get number from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003683/javascript-get-number-from-string)

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
function() {

var element = document.querySelector('*[id^="bew-price"]');
var price = element.innerHTML.replace(/\u00A3/g, '');
var trueprice = price.replace(/,/g , "");


return trueprice;

}
```