# read particular number from a expression

Tags: typescript

I am trying to read a particular number from an expression.

I want to read the digit from below expression.

```
ID:jv.link.weight:234231
```

in the above string, I want to read the number `234231` using typescript.

can anyone suggest me any logic how to read this? I am new to typescript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract ("get") a number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003683/extract-get-a-number-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
getNumber(str) { 
    let number = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
    return number;
}
```

Comment: in typescript, it is giving an error that .replace is not a function.

Comment: its working for me. pass your string as parameter to getNumber.It will return 234231

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex with string.match():

```
const expression = "ID:jv.link.weight:234231";
expression.match(/(\d+)/g)[0]
```

Which will return `234231`

Comment: in typescript, it is giving an error that .match is not a function