# Getting the integers from text of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have an HTML element ("summary-people") which contains the text: `"People: 2"`, for example.

I want to just get the number from this. Is there any way I can extract the number as an int from the HTML element? I am very new to JQuery and Javascript and would appreciate any help. However, here's what I've tried already:

```
function getNumberOfPeople(people) {
    var number = $("#summary-people").text(); 
    // the above line returns "People: 2" 
    var text = number;
    var integer = parseInt(text, 10);
    return integer;
}
```

I'm not even sure if what I am trying to do is possible but I feel there must be a way somehow to extract just the number?

Comment: Just split your string on the ": " and take the [1] so you only have the number left :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract ("get") a number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003683/extract-get-a-number-from-a-string)

Comment: Thanks @Jérémy - how would this work exactly? I can split the string, but how do I access the number? By index?

Comment: Yes @Jordan1993 like that :  
split(': ')[1]

Comment: More specifically: `var i = parseInt(text.split(":")[1], 10)`

Comment: You definitely **do not want** to use a regex to extract the digits (as *all* the answers so far suggest) as it will seriously mess up.  eg "People: 2, towns: 3" will give you 23, not 2.  Parse it as you need it.

Comment: "People: 2" **for example** - what other formats could it take?  If it's always "People: nnnn" then use `indexOf` to extract from beyond the text or `replace` to remove the text.  Depends on what else it could contain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to extract the numbers from a string. Note that this will work on all string formats and will not split the numbers if they are written together ex: `"qw11e" = 11`

```js
var string = "test12;:/()/()4ydewb7329::;;djew";
var numbers = string.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

As no one shared the split way so far, here you go

```js
$(function() {
  var textToInt = parseInt($("#summary-people").text().split(': ')[1]);
  console.log(textToInt)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="summary-people">People: 2</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var txt = "People: 2";
var numb = txt.match(/\d/g);
numb = numb.join("");
alert (numb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
console.log(parseInt("People: 2".replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' )))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var txt = "People: 2";
var numb = Number(txt.split(" ")[1]);
alert(numb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) against just digits after the space in the text:

```js
function getNumberOfPeople(people) {
  var text = $("#summary-people").text();
  var number = text.match(/ \d+/)[0];
  var parsedNumber = parseInt(number, 10);
  return parsedNumber;
}

console.log(getNumberOfPeople());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="summary-people">54People: 22</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
var index = text.indexOf(':');
var numb = text.substring(index+2);
return numb;
```