# can i Filtering number from a message?

Tags: discord, discord.js

can i Filtering number from a message? If you write letters and numbers only send the number

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  let command = message.content.split(" ")[0];
  command = command.slice(prefix.length);

  let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);



if (command == "s") {

  message.channel.send(args.(isNaN))
    message.delete();
  }
});
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10003709/8289918) may help (`string.replace( /^\D+/g, '')`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use `replace` reg for this.

```js
    client.on('message', message => {
        let numbers = Number(message.content.replace(/\D/g, ''))
    });
```

```js
let message = {
  content:"IZ1zasd@221sz!()_"
}
let numbers = Number(message.content.replace(/\D/g, ''))
console.log(numbers)
```