# Get <li> text number using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i am trying to get li tag text value using js but i am not getting the expected output
i.e ("Pens").

I have added a code snippet.

Note - **I cannot change html**.

```js
console.log(jQuery('#accordionItem li span').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="accordionItem" class="filter_middle-stage2-list_wrapper">
  <li style="font-weight: bold;">Pens<span>(1200)</span></li>
</div>
```

Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Does this question solve your problem? [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Comment: Yes it solves the issue. Thankyou

Comment: Glad it works now :) If you can mark it as a duplicate, please do that so people will find the question with all the good answers. If you can't I'll just flag it as a duplicate and a moderator will mark it

Comment: Hello, it still have issue, so can't mark as a duplicate.

Comment: Hello. Are you expecting a "Pens(1200)" or "Pens"?

Comment: Pens is what i am expecting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I understand you want the text of the `li` without the text of the `span`.
So you can use the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function to do it like so:

```js
console.log($('#accordionItem li').text().replace($('#accordionItem li span').text(), ''));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="accordionItem" class="filter_middle-stage2-list_wrapper">
  <li style="font-weight: bold;">Pens<span>(1200)</span></li>
</div>
```

if you want a more general solution that will get you just the text of the `li` without any of its children that would be a better solution:

```js
console.log($('#accordionItem li').contents().get(0).nodeValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="accordionItem" class="filter_middle-stage2-list_wrapper">
  <li style="font-weight: bold;">Pens<span>(1200)</span></li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `text` method like below:

```
console.log($('#accordionItem li span').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be selecting the `<span>` tag on your jQuery selector.
Although I'd suggest using the text method to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**No jQuery needed.**
Since you have an element with ID, you can [access it directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434388/104380), and [get the node's text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) and simply [remove any non-digit characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19496337/104380), and you'll be left with the numeral value you are after.

The benefit of this method is the irrelevance of the DOM structure - it will always work for that element (with that ID), but can be applied to any `<li>` element, regardless if it has a `<span>` child (or any other children)

```js
console.log( 
  accordionItem.children[0].firstChild.textContent
)
```

```html
<div id="accordionItem" class="filter_middle-stage2-list_wrapper">
  <li style="font-weight: bold;">Pens<span>(1200)</span></li>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to console "Pens" not 1200