# How can I extract each integer or float (positive or negative) from a string in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, numbers, floating

This is my code. It still returns null and I do not know why!

```js
var tName = "18.56x^2   -   5.45x  -3.78";
abc = tName.replace(/x/g, "").replace("^2", "").replace(/\s/g, "");
console.log(abc);

$re = "/-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?/m";
$str = abc.toString();
console.log($str.match($re));
```

Comment: just a hint you can use `https://regex101.com/` to debug your RegExp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003683/extract-a-number-from-a-string-javascript This could help

Comment: Also the `$str = abc.toString();` is unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

- not quote the regex AND
- not escape the \d AND
- add the global flag

Have a try with this

```js
const $re = /-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/mg,
      tName = "18.56x^2   -   5.45x  -3.78",
      abc = tName.replace(/x/g, "").replace("^2", "").replace(/\s/g, ""),
      nums = [...abc.matchAll($re)].map(m => m[0]);
console.log(abc)
console.log(nums)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is fine, you just set it up as a string instead of a regex literal.

When you are building RegExp constants, you want to either use the `RegExp()` constructor (for building from strings) or simply a regex literal. You are currently building a normal string that *looks* like a regex, but isn't.

Try edit this line to the following:

```js
$re = /-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/m;
```

Edit:

To access the string itself, you just need to use index 0.

```js
var mat = $str.match($re);
console.log(mat[0])
```

Comment: thanks it worked, however I did not get what I wanted I think my regex is incorrect...

Comment: i got : [ '18.56', index: 0, input: '18.56-5.45-3.78', groups: undefined ]

Comment: Yes that is a 'match object' try add a `[0]` at the end to reference the matching string.

Answer (score 1):

use regexp (not String) as param of `String.prototype.match()` like this:

```js
var tName = "18.56x^2   -   5.45x  -3.78";
abc = tName.replace(/x/g, "").replace("^2", "").replace(/\s/g, "");

$re = /-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/m;
$str = abc.toString();
console.log($str.match($re));
```