# how to split a string with anything that is not a number

Tags: javascript, split

**string input:**

"12 apples, 3 oranges, 10 grapes"

**solution:**

`let arr= inputString.split(" ");`

**issue to solve:**

how would I go about splitting with anything that isn't a number?

**string examples:**

- no spaces

  - `12apples,3oranges,10grapes`
- numbers that are inside `()`

  - `there are some (12) digits 5566 in this 770 string 239` (i want only 12, 5566, 770, 239)
- string of numbers having math done on them

  - `33+22` (should be split into 33 and 22)

**what i thought could work:**

`arr= inputString.split("isNaN");`

Comment: Why do you need to *split*? It seems like you'd want to do the exact opposite and *match* items that are *only numbers*.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10003709/17175441

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```js
const str = '12apples,3oranges,10grapes';

const splitString = str.match(/(?:\d+\.)?\d+/g);

console.log(splitString);
```

Comment: I think the asker wants to parse an array of the numbers from the input string.

Comment: True. Thanks for the clarity. I amended the code to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = "12 apples, 3 oranges, 10 grapes"
let arr = str.match(/\d+(.\d+)?/g)
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = "12apples,3oranges,10grapes"

console.log(str.split(/[^\d]/g).filter(e => e))

str = "there are some (12) digits 5566 in this 770 string 239"

console.log(str.split(/[^\d]/g). filter(e => e))

str="33+22"

console.log(str.split(/[^\d]/g). filter(e => e))
```