# How to get numbers separated by any delimiter (space or any non numeric character)

Tags: javascript, regex

How to get numbers separated by any delimiter (space or any non numeric character).

I tried
Input string: `"111,256 323| 78987 & 6543".split(/,| /),`

but then it requires me to specify the delimiter. What Regex can I use to split the numbers and get like `[111, 256, 323, 78987, 6543]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I extract a number from a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003683/how-can-i-extract-a-number-from-a-string-in-javascript). Scroll down and you'll find answers on how to extract multiple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this :

```
let numberPattern = /\d+/g;
let numbersArr = "111,256 323| 78987 & 6543".match(numberPattern)
console.log(numbersArr)
```

The result must be like that :
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjBEy.png)

Answer (score 2):

To split by non numeric characters:

```
"111,256 323| 78987 & 6543".split(/[^\d]+/)
```

If you want to keep decimals:

```
"111,256 323| 78987 & 6543".split(/[^0-9.]+/)
```

If on top of that you want to get an array of numbers, map the strings to numbers:

```
"111,256 323| 78987 & 6543".split(/[^\d]+/).map(n => Number(n))
```