# How to remove any number characters from a string

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my current attempt which is not working:

```
  const word = "abcd123";
  const filteredNum = word.split("").filter((e) => Number(e) !== NaN);
  console.log(filteredNum);
```

Comment: use the `isNan()` function

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10003709/7685955%5D):

```js
const word = "abcd123";
const result = word.match(/\d+/)[0];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

using isNan() function

```js
    let word = "abcd123";
    let filteredNum = word.split("").filter((e) => !isNaN(e));
    console.log(filteredNum);
    console.log(filteredNum.join(""))
```