# How to cut part of string in vanilla js to send like as parameter on API

Tags: javascript

I have a little problem with this [url](http://194.141.118.43:9191/floodguard/#).

I want to get only the numbers on the first drop down and send it like as paramater on API.

[image: dropdown]

I create a object with properties:

```
const dataAPI = { nameStation: '', nameStationNumber: '', dateStation: '', dataHours: '' }
```

and I want dataAPI.nameStationNumber to save only a number of clicked value.

With this code I get only this string for example:

```
Chepelarska - 18694 - HPoint-Water level 

dataAPI.nameStation = e.target.innerHTML.replace(/.*\+\s?/, '');
```

How can I cut only `18694` from `река Чепеларска - гр. Асеновград + Chepinska - 10084 - HPoint-Water level`

Can I get example how to do that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I extract a number from a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003683/how-can-i-extract-a-number-from-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Can I get example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex `/[^\d]+/` (replace `[^]` anything that does not match `\d` (number))

```js
let string = 'река Чепеларска - гр. Асеновград + Chepinska - 10084 - HPoint-Water level';
let result = string.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this will fail if you have two or more numbers in a string, it will concatenate all digits

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the first number from a string do this:

```js
const input = 'река Чепеларска - гр. Асеновград + Chepinska - 10084 - HPoint-Water level';
let result = input.replace(/^[^0-9]*([0-9]*).*$/, '$1');
console.log(result);
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `[^0-9]*` -- scan over anything not a digit
- `([0-9]*)` -- capture group with all digits
- `.*$` -- anything left over
- replacement uses the capture group: `'$1'`