# How would I use innerHTML (or similar) to obtain purely integers from divs in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Code is as follows:

```html
<div class="empty player card3">6 Spades</div>
<div class="empty player card4">10 Hearts</div>
```

I need to add the numbers (6 & 10 in this case) together for a score count. How would I do this in JavaScript in a function?

Edit: forgot to add that the "number" could be J, Q, K, or A (10,10,10,11). Would there be a quick convert for this as well?

Comment: consider the mv* patterns that exist. don't use the dom as state

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract number from a string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033334/how-to-extract-number-from-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing and filling-in the blanks from your question,
I've coded a function to add cards.
It takes three arguments:

- Boolean `empty`: should it look for class `empty`?
- String `who`: for example, `"player"`.
- Array of Integers `cardNumbers`: for example, `[3, 4]`.

It takes the substring before the first space of all the div's that match the classes and card numbers' text content, and stores in a temporary array `values`.

It then sums, with initial value `0`, 10 for JQK, 11 for A, and number value for the rest - `+String` is the shortest way to get a Number out of a number string.

```js
function cardsValue(empty, who, cardNumbers) {
  var values = cardNumbers.map(
    currentValue => document.querySelector(
      (empty?".empty":"") +
      ("." + who) +
      (".card" + currentValue)
    )
    .textContent
    .split(" ")
    [0]
  );
  return (
    values.reduce(
      (accumulator, currentValue) => {
        accumulator +=
        ["J", "Q", "K"].includes(currentValue)?10:
        currentValue == "A"?11:
        +currentValue;
        return accumulator;
      }, 0
    )
  );
}

console.log("Player: "+cardsValue(true, "player", [3, 4]));
console.log("Computer: "+cardsValue(true, "computer", [9, 10,11]));
```

```html
<div class="empty player card3">6 Spades</div>
<div class="empty player card4">10 Hearts</div>
<br>
<div class="empty computer card9">K Diamonds</div>
<div class="empty computer card10">A Clubs</div>
<div class="empty computer card11">7 Diamonds</div>
```

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
[Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
[String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
[Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

I don't know if class `empty` is important for selection,
Nor the card number.
If not: you can sum all `"player"`, `"computer"`, `"player2"`, etc.:

```js
function cardsValue(who) {
  var divs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("." + who));
  var values = divs.map(
    currentValue =>
    currentValue
    .textContent
    .split(" ")
    [0]
  );
  return (
    values.reduce(
      (accumulator, currentValue) => {
        accumulator +=
        ["J", "Q", "K"].includes(currentValue)?10:
        currentValue == "A"?11:
        +currentValue;
        return accumulator;
      }, 0
    )
  );
}

console.log("Player: "+cardsValue("player"));
console.log("Computer: "+cardsValue("computer"));
```

```html
<div class="empty player card3">6 Spades</div>
<div class="empty player card4">10 Hearts</div>
<br>
<div class="empty computer card9">K Diamonds</div>
<div class="empty computer card10">A Clubs</div>
<div class="empty computer card11">7 Diamonds</div>
```

[Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time Oren. The second function was just what I needed. Class Empty is needed, just haven't renamed it yet tbh!

Comment: @Mathias-Sode, glad to have helped, you are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

```
function addCardNumbers() {
  const card3 = document.querySelector(".empty.player.card3");
  const card4 = document.querySelector(".empty.player.card4");
  
  // Remove every non-digit character from the text
  // and convert them to numbers
  const card3Number = Number(card3.textContent.replace(/\D/g, ""));
  const card4Number = Number(card4.textContent.replace(/\D/g, ""));

  return card3Number + card4Number;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take this way:

```
function addCardNumbers() {
  const card3 = document.querySelector(".empty.player.card3");
  const card4 = document.querySelector(".empty.player.card4");
  
  return parseInt(card3.textContent) + parseInt(card4.textContent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `split()` to make sure you get the numeric part, then `parseInt(value, 10)`, to parse a `value` using a base-10 system.  If you fail to split and identify the numeric part, you'll possibly get `NaN` for a value like "joker".  If you're not sure where the number is, you'll need to `forEach()` the results of `split(' ')` and use `isNan()` to find the number.  And, if you don't indicate `10`, you could get a base-8 answer...

> If the input string begins with "0" (a zero), radix is assumed to be 8 (octal)... (Source: [Developer.Mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt))

```js
console.log(parseInt(document.getElementById("6ofspades").innerHTML.split(' ')[0], 10));
console.log(parseInt(document.getElementById("10ofhearts").innerHTML.split(' ')[0], 10));
```

```html
<div id="6ofspades" class="empty player card3">6 Spades</div>
<div id="10ofhearts" class="empty player card4">10 Hearts</div>
```